# What happens to a movable object when its insertion in an std::set fails?

Tags: c++, c++11

What happens if to a movable object if I call
`std::set<>::insert` on it, and the insertion doesn't take place
because there is already an object with the same key present in
the set.  In particular, is the following valid:

```
struct Object
{
    std::string key;
    //  ...

    struct OrderByKey
    {
        bool operator()( Object const& lhs, Object const& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs.key < rhs.key;
        }
    };

    Object( Object&& other )
        : key(std::move(other.key))
    // ...
    {
    }
};
```

and:

```
std::set<Object, Object::OrderByKey> registry;
void
register(Object&& o)
{
    auto status = registry.insert(std::move(o));
    if (!status.second)
        throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate entry for " + o.key);
}
```

After the `registry.insert`, when no insertion takes place, has
`o` been moved or not.  (If it might have been moved, I need to
save a copy of the string before hand, in order to use it in the
error message.  (And yes, I know that I can always write:

```
throw std::runtime_error( "Duplicate entry for " + status->first.key );
```

Which is what I'll probably do.  But I would still like to know
what the standard says about this.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `std::move()`ed object passed to a standard library function should be considered to be moved from: the library is free to consider the object to be its only reference, i.e., it may move from it even if it doesn't use it. The relevant clause is 17.6.4.9 [res.on.arguments] paragraph 2, third bullet (it seems identical in C++11 and C++14):

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference, the implementation may assume that this parameter is a unique reference to this argument. ...

Answer (score 3):

This is (very simmilar to) LWG Active issue [2362](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4117.html#2362) which deals with emplace. IIRC the sentiment is that it should be guaranteed that the object is only moved iff it is inserted/emplaced. With emplace it seems to be not trivial to achieve. I do not remember if the situation is easier for insert.

Comment: It's along the same lines, and I would expect that both questions would have the same answer.  (Which is, for the moment: even the committee doesn't know.)  Not very reassuring (but typical when new features are involved).

Comment: It is conceptually simpler to for an `insert` to leave the argument object unchanged. The argument to `insert` is an actual object, whereas `emplace` must construct an object from the arguments (consuming rvalues) *before* it can perform the look up to determine if the object is already in the set.

Comment: The case of `insert` is simpler than the case of `emplace`, since the key is already built in `insert` and the comparator run on the argument `key` and the internal nodes. In the case of `emplace` there is no way of telling the comparator something like: *given this building blocks for a key, but without building the key, can you tell me if it would be smaller than the key in this node?*

Answer (score 3):

The third bullet of [res.on.arguments]/1 from N3936:

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation **may assume that
>   this parameter is a unique reference to this argument**. [ *Note:* If the parameter is a generic parameter of the form `T&&` and an lvalue of type `A` is bound, the argument binds to an lvalue reference (14.8.2.1) and thus is not covered by the previous sentence. *—end note* ] [ *Note:* If a program casts an lvalue to an xvalue while passing that lvalue to a library function (e.g. by calling the function with the argument `move(x)`), the program is effectively asking that function to treat that lvalue as a temporary. The implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the argument was an lvalue. *—end note* ]

despite on its face being about aliasing, can be interpreted as allowing the implementation to do virtually anything to an argument that is passed to a standard library function bound to an rvalue reference. As [Fabio says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811833/923854), there are situations in which tightening this specification could be useful, and the committee is looking at some of them.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  If I interpret it correctly, it means that I can't assume anything one way or another.  (I suspected something like this; that there was a blanket clause covering the issue.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer your last question

> I would still like to know what the standard says about this

the standard specifies what happen with `insert(t)` in `Table 102 - Associative container requirements`, p717 of N3376 (emphasis mine):

> Requires: If t is a non-const rvalue expression, value_type shall be MoveInsertable into X; otherwise, value_type shall be CopyInsertable into X.
>
> Effects: Inserts t **if and only if there is no element in the container with key equivalent to the key of t**. The bool component of the returned pair is true if and only if the insertion takes place, and the iterator component of the pair points to the element with key equivalent to the key of t.

so I'd say that nothing should happen and that your `Object` is still valid and not unspecified state.

**EDIT**: As someone pointed out in the comment, this may actually depends on the implementation as it requires explicitly that the set is not modified, but states no explicit requirement on the argument and whether it's been moved or not.

Comment: I found this description too, but I'm not 100% sure that this entirely rules out the possibility of a valid implementation that does move t. As long as the collection will not contain t upon return, doesn't the implementation follow the spec? There's probably no good reason to do such a thing of course.

Comment: @heinrichj there are some words in the standard about "not doing stuff that isn't required to do" somewhere.

Comment: Well, I think the standards is pretty clear. If there's already an element with the key of t, it _does not insert_, so nothing happens.

Comment: Like @heinrichj I'd found this before even posting.  It doesn't really address the issue.  The question is when does the actual move occur; when the function is called, or only when the item is actually inserted?

Comment: The assumption in this answer does not hold. The requirement is that the set is not modified, but there is no requirement as of what the state of the argument to 'insert' is. A conforming implementation can build a node by moving the key (and emptying the argument to `insert`) and then figure out that it cannot insert the value into the set (already present) and fail. It would adhere to the requirement in this answer and yet the key may have changed in the process